# How to display contents from mysql table in android?

Tags: android, mysql, jsp

I am developing an android app, using eclipse jsp and mysql. In this I need to display all rows of a specific table in android layout under the correct labels(for ex: I have a table called demo in mysql with fields id name and address, I want display all the rows of demo table in android in table format(id,name,address)). How can I do it with jsp and android? Someone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use array list and bean class to get and display data u want to show

```
 public ArrayList<SigninBean> getUser() {
            //      onCreate(getWritableDatabase());
            SigninBean sBean = new SigninBean();
            ArrayList<SigninBean> arList = new ArrayList<>();
            // String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_Name + " WHERE "
            //         + KEY_DATE + " = ?";
            // String[] args={tag};
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE;
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);


            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {

                    String d = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_signin_date));
                    String photo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_signin_photo));
                    String gender = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_signin_gender));
                    String time = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_signin_time));
                    String accurate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_Signin_accurate));
                    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_signin_name));
                    String city = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_signin_city));
                    String country = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_signin_country));

                    sBean.setName(name);
                    sBean.setPhoto(photo);
                    sBean.setTime(time);
                    sBean.setGender(gender);
                    sBean.setCity(city);
                    sBean.setCountry(country);
                    sBean.setDate(d);
                    sBean.setAccurate(accurate);
                    Log.e("User values r=========>", "" + d + " " + name + " " + city + " " + country + " " + d);

                    cursor.moveToNext();
                    arList.add(sBean);
                }
            }
```

Comment: I mean retrieving data from mysql database in a local server, not from sqlite. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Is it in Json Form ?

Comment: Not a json form.Is it possible only in json form?

Comment: you can try this :-http://www.geeks.gallery/retrieve-data-from-mysql-database-using-php-and-displaying-it-by-tableview-in-android/